# Create output file names based on input file name in OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, bioinformatics, sequencing

I have this script

```
annotatepeaks.pl file mm9 -annStats filename > output
```

I use this script to run one job:

```
annotatepeaks.pl file.xls mm9 -annStats file_stat.xls > file_ann.xls
```

Since I have multiple files and want to run in batch (add `Batchparallel.pl`)

```
Batchparallel.pl annotatepeaks.pl ann.xls mm9 -annStats filename -f *.xls
```

that basically runs parallel command for the one job. The problem is `-annStats` only give me one output file. How to specify the file name so that it takes the input name and use it for output for that specific flag (`-annStats`).

I am very new to this so hopefully my question makes sense for everyone.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't give very specific help without seeing your code, but if you modify annotatepeaks.pl to write to a file instead of printing to STDOUT, you can use something like "my $outfile = $infile . '_out.xls'" to use base the output name on the input name.

Comment: Thanks! The script is quite long so I don't know how to to attach the perl file here otherwise I can copy and paste.